# how to select a list of key value in Oracle DB as single string?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have comments table like this

```
USER        MODE     TYPE   REQ_ID  R_ID  C_VALUE
weblogic    EDIT    OUTPUT  10040   700   teee
ashraf      EDIT    OUTPUT  10040   700   yes
```

I want to select a single string like the following

```
weblogic: teee
ashraf:   yes
```

Comment: You want to know how to concatenate `user` and `': '` and `c_value`? Google Oracle + string concatenation. Or are the two result rows supposed to be one string containing a line break?

Comment: two result rows supposed to be one string containing a line break ? 
yes it supposed to single string with any delimiter ?

Comment: Then you must concatenate the single strings of a table row with `||` and then use `LISTAGG` over this expression to get one final result row with only one string.

Comment: select  LISTAGG(user_name||' : '||comment_text, ', ')  user_comments
from comments e 

i've tried this but its not working

Comment: It is not working? What does this mean? Are you getting an error? Too many rows? No row? Text converted to Chinese? Please don't ever simply say "it is not working" instead of describing how the result you are getting is different from what you want. In your case it may help to look up the syntax for `LISTAGG`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: sorry man , i was getting missing the withting group 
and this has fixed the problem
select  LISTAGG(user_name ||' : '||comment_text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_name)  "user_comments"
from comments

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate the values:

```
select user||':'||c_value
from the_table;
```

Note that if either `user` or `c_value` is null the result of the concatenation will also be null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want fixed length strings.  If so, you can use `rpad()` and some string length calculations:

```
select "user" || rpad(':', 10 - length("user"), ' ') || c_value
from (select 'weblogic' as "user", 'teee' as c_value from dual union all
      select 'ashraf', 'yes' from dual
     ) x;
```